# PHP / CakePHP session time outs not working as expected

Tags: php, session, cakephp

This is a PHP/CakePHP question as I think they concern one and the same thing!

So in my application I have set the session timeouts to be quite low. 20 mins. This is for security measures to make sure that users don't stay logged in for long periods of inactivity however I've noticed this isn't quite what is happening.

What I expect to happen = The session last 20 minutes of inactivity.

What actually happens = The session expires after 20 minutes whether they are using the app or not so basically if they doing postbacks here, there and everywhere, they will still be logged out after 20 minutes.

Is this normal behaviour? And if so how can I make it so that sessions don't expire if the user is still using the application?

Comment: What do you mean tried? I have set the session time out to be 20 mins as explained in my post. But as I have explained it doesn't seem to work on inactivity rather on 20 minutes regardless.

Comment: Are you using a session function, or PHP sessions? Are you using your own cookies?

Comment: I'm using the built in CakePHP sessions, default settings apart from the timeout number. Should interactivity prevent sessions from expiring???

Comment: possibly related to http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2901-bug-session-data-lost-after-24-mins-because-sessiongc_maxlifetime-not-set-anywhere

Comment: Do PHP sessions last longer than their expiry time if the user keeps interacting with the site?